# Determining what objects fall within a selection rectangle (marquee)

Tags: vb.net, selection, marquee

I'm writing a program that (amongst other things) provides an IDE-like environment for the user where they can select one or more objects with a rectangualr selection tool.

All selections will be a simple rectangle, and all selectable objects will be simple rectangles as well.

I already have the code (VB.Net) to create the rubber-banding effect visually - what I need is an efficient algorithm that will tell me what objects have at least a portion of their area within the final selection rectangle.

If it helps to visualize, what I want to do would be identical to dragging a selection box over icons on the Windows desktop... whichever icons have even a portion of their areas located within that selection marquee are highlighted (selected).

Any help would be appreciated... thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Rect1 As New Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20)
Dim Rect2 As New Rectangle(5, 5, 20, 20)

Debug.Print(Rect1.IntersectsWith(Rect2))
```

Comment: That does not check if one rectangle contains another.

Comment: /facepalm
Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

[IntersectsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectanglef.intersectswith%28VS.90%29.aspx) works as BigFunger already has mentioned. But aditionally you should check if a rectangle [contains](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F0kh3ee9e.aspx&rct=j&q=rectangle%20contains&ei=DxbbTNe9D82eOsfjxcAJ&usg=AFQjCNE0_zm5w8da5_TrnQtEkUg1IDJBpw&sig2=RLvb2VZlDZgXyrHTblWQhw&cad=rja) another rectangle(intersectsWith only checks for intersection).

A small sample-form that demonstrates it:

```
Public Class SelectionRectangle
    Private first As Point
    Private allRectangles As New List(Of RectangleF)

    Private Sub form_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
        first = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
    End Sub

    Private Sub form_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
        Dim p As New Pen(Brushes.Black, 2)
        Dim g As Graphics
        Dim second As New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        Dim x, y, w, h As Int32
        x = DirectCast(IIf(first.X > second.X, second.X, first.X), Int32)
        y = DirectCast(IIf(first.Y > second.Y, second.Y, first.Y), Int32)
        w = Math.Abs(second.X - first.X)
        h = Math.Abs(second.Y - first.Y)
        Dim nextRec As New RectangleF(x, y, w, h)
        Dim intersects As Boolean = False
        For Each rec As RectangleF In allRectangles
            If rec.Contains(nextRec) OrElse rec.IntersectsWith(nextRec) Then
                intersects = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not intersects Then
            p.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot
            g = Me.CreateGraphics()
            g.DrawLine(p, first.X, first.Y, second.X, first.Y)
            g.DrawLine(p, second.X, second.Y, first.X, second.Y)
            g.DrawLine(p, first.X, first.Y, first.X, second.Y)
            g.DrawLine(p, second.X, second.Y, second.X, first.Y)
            allRectangles.Add(nextRec)
        Else
            Beep()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**UPDATE**: changed this code to 1.first check in both directions and 2. and more important for you: checks also if one rectangle not only intersects another but additionally if it **contains** another.